# Split the result of group_concat function

Tags: php, mysql

I have here a mysql query to display information from database inside of jquery accordion. I used GROUP_CONCAT to group the supplier and code.

Here's my Table Structure.

```
id    | supplier  |  code
--------------------------
   1  |     DELL  |  9001
   2  |     DELL  |  9002  
   3  |     HP    |  3201
   4  |     HP    |  4112
```

Query

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "table");
  $result = $mysqli->query("Select (SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT code) FROM table) as a, (SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT supplier) FROM table) as b");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<h3>'.$row['b'].'</h3>';
echo '<div>'.$row['a'].'</div>';
}
```

Result in localhost

```
    a     | b
----------------
9001,9002 | DELL
```

What I expect to be the output in html per accordion div

```
DELL        
9001
9002
-----
HP        
3201
4112
```

so that I can make a link for each code like

```
<a href="">'.$row['a'].'</a>
```

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: So why use `GROUP_CONCAT` at all if you need all results in their own rows?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky That's why I'm asking.

Comment: If you output to PHP, why would you need GROUP_CONCAT at all? That's just silly! Just loop through an ordered array.